# Abstracting communication with an API in JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, api

I am trying to achieve a layer which I can supply custom objects to and have them committed to an external API. The idea is to create an object and then pass it to a datamanager of some sort to serialise the object and send it to an external API.

I am guessing I could achieve some sort of basic serialisation by looping through the fields of the class with something like:

```
Type classType = typeof(TestClass);
foreach(FieldInfo field in classType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
}
```

Would there be a better way to deal with breaking an object to be sent as JSON to an API? The ultimate end goal is to be able to receive the object back through a GET request and have it converted to a C# class through something like json.net.

Comment: You are basically asking if you can convert an object into JSON directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look and [Newtonsoft's JSON library](http://james.newtonking.com/json). With it you can do stuff like:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small"
//  ]
//}
```

It is also available in [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Comment: We actually use this library already and I just hadn't read through the documentation properly - thanks for pointing it out for me!